# QGIS & GeoTIFF clipping Error "-srcwin 5897 137 0 0 falls outside raster size of 11083x4158 or is otherwise illegal."

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I'm trying to clip a GeoTIFF  file  and unfortunately I'm getting the following

```
Error "-srcwin 5897 137 0 0 falls outside raster size of 11083x4158 or is otherwise illegal."
```

From another post here I found out my projection was not set correctly. I did set the projection by clicking CRS status window at the bottom right and selecting Enable "on the fly" and WGS 84 and then apply. I'm  still getting the same error. Any idea how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling on the fly reprojection only affects how the data is displayed in the map window. It does not affect analysis. You need to use appropriate coordinates in your Geotif's coordinates.

Comment: Okay , As I'm totally new to QGIS and GIS in general I changed the project projection from Settings > Options .. selected EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 & use project CRS. IS that correct ?  The geotif file i loaded to QGS its projection was changed using the following command gdalwarp Miami91South.tif Miami91SouthOut.tif -t_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"

Comment: You don't need to re-project, if the raster you want to clip is properly projected all you need to do is right-click on it use the Set Project CRS from Layer option.